# Spring Batch load into LDAP

Tags: spring, ldap, spring-batch, batch-processing, ldif

I have a Spring Batch requirement to read data from CSV file and load into LDAP repository.

Would like to know if there is any example online to help me understand the steps and configurations involved to achieve this using Spring Batch.

Comment: I have a link which for Spring-Batch but not for LDAP. Hope it helps https://bigzidane.wordpress.com/2016/09/06/spring-batch-maven-hibernate-oracle-and-intellij/

Comment: another simple example, but for mysql https://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-example-csv-file-to-database/

Comment: @NghiaDo Thanks. I am looking for LDAP related Batch program.

Comment: @SundararajGovindasamy Thanks. I do have this sample. I am looking at Spring with LDAP functionality.

Comment: Hi. Could you please update us about how you performed if you could find a proper solution. Thank you!